# Ember Error: Attempting to inject unknown injection: 'service:intl'

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I've upgraded my ember application and its dependencies from lower version to version 2.3.0 following the steps here https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/releases/tag/v2.3.0-beta.1. But while trying to run my application I'm getting an error.

Error: Attempting to inject an unknown injection: `service:intl`
at Object.Registry.validateInjections (ember.debug.js:2277).

What possibly the cause of this error?

Comment: Sounds like you didn't properly install `ember-intl`. When you `ember init`, did you overwrite `package.json`?

Comment: ah, I see. Yeah I did overwrite it. And it seem's that it's not installed. Thanks @locks